# XJB file with translations

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjb

I generated my JAXB classes using XJC tool. Almost everything looks fine, but the schema elements are named in German not English.
I want to rename fileds in classes to be en english and I know that I need to create XJB file with custom bindings.
The problem is that schema is huge and it will be much easier if I could generate XJB file for default binding where I would have class names and fields in German and I will simply translate it.
Do you know any tools which can help me generating such default XJB file?

Answer (score 0):

What about using an XSLT? You could simply pass the schema through the XSLT, so it renames the elements into English. Or u could even create an XSLT to generate the XJB file.